# ImageView resizes when I addView

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

All I want to do is grab an image from the web (Succeess!) and display it at whatever resolution it is origionaly, withing a scrollview.  however, when i addView to the scrollview, the image gets resized, (as opposed to when if I called setContentView on teh activity itself, where as I get the result i'm looking for.

```
ScrolView sv = new ScrollView(this);
addContentView(sv);
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
putDrawableFromUrlIntoIv(iv, url); //this fills iv with a drawable
sv.addView(iv);
```

Not much code to show, but I figured I'd show it anyway.  d is, in the test case, a 480x800 but it will be different sizes.  It displays shrunken on the screen.  What is going on?

EDIT: addContentView(sv) comes before sv.addView(d);  Is this problematic?  I do this because... i'm actually lazy-loading the drawable in reality, passing

I have also tried the following as a test :

```
{
   ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
   ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
   Drawable d = a_480x800_drawable;
   iv.setImageDrawable(d);
   sv.addView(iv, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   setContentView(sv);
}
```

The result is an image that is too small, who's upper left corner is fit to the upper left corner of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding layout parameters to the ImageView,

```
sr.addView(d, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

Drawable d = a_480x800_drawable;

iv.setImageDrawable(d);

sv.addView(iv, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

setContentView(sv);

}

//instead of this use
{
     ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
     ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
     Drawable d = a_480x800_drawable;

     iv.setImageDrawable(d);

     LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

     lp.topMargin = 50; //or whatever u like

     lp.leftMargin = 50;

     sv.addView(iv, lp);
     setContentView(sv);
```

}

Comment: Please add a description of the changes you made and why you made them!